# Keycloak - Access-Control-Allow-Origin header missing

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I’ve added * to the Web Origins for my NodeJS Connect client as well as my NodeJS API client. I’ve also added `enable-cors: true` to my keycloak.json. Even with both of these, I still can’t redirect to Keycloak from my NodeJS API. Note that I'm not using the JS client. The `keycloak.protect()` function is trying to tell the browser to redirect to Keycloak but it won't because of the missing CORS header. Is there anything else I need to do to enable CORS?

Comment: Is your ```Access Type``` set to ```public``` and ```Valid Redirect URIs``` to e.g. ```http(s)://yourhost:3000/*```?

Comment: Yeah both of those are set

Comment: I'm not using the JS library, just the NodeJS adapter. I'm hitting an endpoint on my server which is then trying to redirect me to Keycloak. Looks like the AJAX call following the 302 redirect is setting my origin to null and the request is also missing the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

Comment: The response from the Keycloak server is also missing the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, which I suspect is the real problem.